# Modified DH Parameters?

Tags: dh-parameters

Is the notation of the geometry of robots from Khalil and Kleinfinger be considered as one of the probably "many" Modified DH Parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Khalil himself says that it is a form of the modified D-H parameters.  See, *e.g.,* Section 2.1 of the 2000 Springer-Verlag book *Advances in Robot Kinematics.*

Comment: Hopefully I can find that book you've suggested. The reason why I'm asking this because currently i'm trying model a 5 DOF revolute manipulator, it is my first model! I'm using Khalil and Dombre book as a reference. After modeling I want plug the results in the rvc toolbox of P. Corke for simulation and all what i know of the rvc toolbox is that they're using standard DH notation and also a modified version.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=2AXoCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=Khalil+and+Kleinfinger++kinematics&source=bl&ots=CgDmV3xRsn&sig=hirCn149Bvfe-CrIs_hjoVkkeSg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinj9-1y7bKAhXhtoMKHYCGA5EQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=Khalil%20and%20Kleinfinger%20%20kinematics&f=false